# Detecting specific installed app in Iphone/android from webpage

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, next.js, universal-link

In our app, we decided to create a customer banner on webpage (mobile screen) to let user download/open the mobile app.
So this AppBanner has a button with two different scenario:

1. if user has the application installed, the button should be `OPEN APP`
2. if user doesn't have the application installed, the button should be `DOWNLOAD APP`

i've been checking to find a proper solution in order to achieve this goal, in some places it mentions that because of some security reasons it's not possible and on the other hand i see some places mentioning about universal link and its feature.

Can you please help me to understand what's the proper way to handle this?is it even possible to have one common solution for both android and ios? Thanks!